# Is there any impact of Changing OU in AD of Farm Admin or Application Admin accounts?

Tags: ad, farm-admin

Ours is a SharePoint 2016 On Prem Farm. It has Farm and App Admin AD accounts.
The Systems team wants to change the OU of these Accounts. Need to know that

**Is there any impact of Changing OU in AD of Farm Admin or Application Admin (used for service applications) accounts?**

I have been searching the net for some time. But not able to get any details or links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No changing the OU is not going to affect the environment in any way.

It will only affect if you are driving any custom utility based on User profile properties.

The best way would be to keep a sync between Active directory and User profile service application by setting up MIM .

This way the User profile service application will always stay in sync with any of the active directory changes and you will also be able to track if your changes affect the environment in any way .